# CentOS 6.7: network is unreachable after a new clean installation

Tags: linux, centos, networking, ping

I have a new clean installation of CentOS 6.7, it is not on a VM, but on a dedicated notebook. During the installation procedure I've configured my WiFi connection and have added it on eth0 pre-configured connection.

I have specified all:

- name of the connection
- SSID
- mode: hoc
- band: automatic
- channel: pre-configured
- MTU: automatic
- checked automatic connection box and available for all users box too

In security section I have inserted WPA & WPA2 Personal, then the corresponding password of the router.

In IPv4 section: automatic (DHCP) method and checked the completion of this connection with IPv4 addressing.

In IPv6 section: ignore method

I log in with root user and corresponding password for have all privileges.

The WiFi spy on the WiFi key of the notebook is on, the router is on and Internet works with other devices.

But if I `ping google.com`, it says:

```
unknown host google.com
```

while if I `ping 8.8.8.8`, it says:

```
Network is unreachable
```

Since I have configured all the connection data and checked the automatic connection box, I expected that the connection would be automatic when I log in.

Is there something that I did wrong? Hope in some friendly advice.

Comment: What is the output of ifconfig, have you disabled iptables

Comment: Are you accessing the computer via a GUI or a terminal?

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot: this is a minimal installation, I access it by terminal and haven't a GUI.

Comment: Here's ifconfig output:

Link encap: Local Loopback
inet addr: 127.0.0.1   Mask: 255.0.0.0
inet6 addr:   ::1/128  Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING    MTU:65536   Metric:1
RX packets:20  errors:0  dropped:0  overruns:0  frame:0
TX packets:20  errors:0  dropped:0  overruns:0  carrier:0  collisions:0  txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:1376  (1.3 KiB)   TX bytes:1376  (1.3 KiB)

I haven't do anything after clean installation, how can I disable iptables? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

will disable the iptables

```
 chkconfig iptables off
```

Comment: no wait please! I'm an idiot: since the notebook is new,I didn't know this, but the spy on wifi key is orange, so it means that it not finds the wifi device. The spy must be blue when wifi is connected, while I though that in that case it would turn off the light.

Anyway your instruction works, but this definitely isn't the problem, there is something that I need to do for grab the wifi signal. Please help, in the meanwhile I'll search a solution too!!

Comment: If you have a GUI, you must be having NetworkManager on your top right hand side of the corner. you can assign IP from there. If isn't showing you the anything that means your drivers is not detected.

Comment: unfortunately I'm using a minimal installation without GUI... maybe I'll install a new version with GUI to make things easy. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Regardless of the actual issue, this answer needs more explanation about why you need to run those commands what they're fixing, otherwise it's not as helpful as it could be.

Comment: default iptables are not having out going rules, it just has SSH enabled

Answer (score 0):

### You can use network manager cli

> ```
> nmcli radio
>
> WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
> enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
> ```

---

> ```
> nmcli device
>
> DEVICE  TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION
>  
> wlan0   wifi      disconnected  --         
> eth0    ethernet  unavailable   --         
> lo      loopback  unmanaged     --
> ```

---

```
nmcli device wifi rescan
nmcli device wifi list
nmcli device wifi connect SSID-Name password wireless-password-here
```